# Offer id MS-AZR-0017P is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-sdk-python, azure-billing-api

I have to get the last bills from my azure account via CLI or python SDK. In both cases, I have a message telling me that my subscription type is not supported:

CLI :

```
# az billing invoice show
UnsupportedSubscriptionType - Offer id MS-AZR-0017P is not supported.
```

Python-SDK :

```
from azure.mgmt.billing import BillingManagementClient
bil_client = BillingManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
for item in bil_client.invoices.list():
    print(item)

azure.mgmt.billing.models.error_response.ErrorResponseException:     (UnsupportedSubscriptionType) Offer id MS-AZR-0017P is not supported.
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Best regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about billing

Comment: Why ? For example this question is discussed here: [link](http://ninocrudele.com/azure-billing-warning-offer-id-ms-azr-0017p-is-not-supported-solved) and [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7389) and for the moment no solution has been found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to give a try by using latest versioned CLI / python-sdk. However, if the issue still persists then follow [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7389) (currently open) GitHub issue for any future updates regarding the similar issue.

Cheers!!

Comment: Hello Krishna-MSFT,
thank you for your reply.
I did not specify it in my message, but I checked to have the last version of AZure CLI:

`az --version`
azure-cli                         2.0.67
billing                            0.2.2

Latest version : [link](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli-billing/)

and of Phyton SDK : 

`# pip show azure`
Name: azure
Version: 4.0.0

Latest version : [link](https://pypi.org/project/azure/)

Yes, there is an issue open on Github, I quote in my comment, but I know that asking the question on stackoverflow can always be a good thing :)